# Type error when replacing an unknown first characters in each item in a list

Tags: python

I have an array with short month names as shown below.

```
dates_array = ['Jan 12', 'Feb 23', 'Mar 24', 'Apr 25', 'Nov 26']
```

I want to change each short month name to the month number followed by `/`.
I would like the resulted dates_array to look like the one below:

```
dates_array = ['1/12', '2/23', '3/24', '4/25', '11/26']
```

The `short_month_to_number` function and the three line program below comes with the following type error:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Here is the program:

```
def short_month_to_number (short_month_name):
    switcher = {

        "Jan": 1,
        "Feb": 2,
        "Mar": 3,
        "Apr": 4,
        "May": 5,
        "Jun": 6,
        "Jul": 7,
        "Aug": 8,
        "Sep": 9,
        "Oct": 10,
        "Nov": 11,
        "Dec": 12
    }
    return (switcher.get(short_month_name))

dates_array = ['Jan 12', 'Feb 23', 'Mar 24', 'Apr 25', 'Nov 26']
dates_array = [dates_array[x].replace(x[:4], short_month_to_number (x[:4])+'/') for x in dates_array]
print (dates_array)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are indexing dates_array with [x] which is string from dates_array. 
Fixing some other indexing and type issues, this gives your desired output:

```
def short_month_to_number (short_month_name):
    switcher = {
        "Jan": 1,
        "Feb": 2,
        "Mar": 3,
        "Apr": 4,
        "May": 5,
        "Jun": 6,
        "Jul": 7,
        "Aug": 8,
        "Sep": 9,
        "Oct": 10,
        "Nov": 11,
        "Dec": 12
    }
    return switcher.get(short_month_name)

dates_array = ['Jan 12', 'Feb 23', 'Mar 24', 'Apr 25', 'Nov 26']
dates_array = [x.replace(x[:4], str(short_month_to_number(x[:3])) + '/') for x in dates_array]
print (dates_array)
```

Answer (score 2):

You have multiple issues:

1. `x` is an item from `dates_array`, not an index. So `dates_array[x]` does not make sense.
2. You are trying to concatenate an `int` (return value of `short_month_to_number`) with a str.
3. `x[:4]` will also contain the space after the month, you should use `x[:3]`.

Try this:

```
dates_array = [x.replace(x[:4], str(short_month_to_number(x[:3])) + '/') for x in dates_array]
```

That being said, you could have also used the date formatting functions in the `datetime` module:

```
from datetime import datetime
print([datetime.strptime(d, '%b %d').strftime('%-m/%d') for d in dates_array])
```

Note that `%-m` is platform specific and not available on Windows. Use the zero padded variant (`%m`) if that is the case.

Comment: Your solution works perfectly. Thank you for your detailed explanation. The first issue I left in by mistake. Thank you for suggesting the date formatting function  because I will need to convert more odd dates formats to the short format. Your idea of using the datetime formatting function will probably save coding time.

Comment: I tried your code that uses the date formatting functions and it came with the following error: ValueError: time data '1/12' does not match format '%b %d'

Comment: It looks like you are passing an already converted date (`1/12`) to the function. You should pass the original format (`Jan 12`)

Comment: I passed the original format and I received  a different error:
ValueError: Invalid format string.

Comment: I think that I found the problem.  .strftime('%-m/%d') would not accept the % -m parameter. However it will work with the %m parameter. The difference is that instead of displaying the Month as a decimal number (%-m) it will display it as a zero-padded decimal number (%m). I used the date formatting function in other cases and it always issued an error when I used the %-m argument.

Comment: Turns out `%-m` is platform specific and is not available on Windows. Updated my answer to reflect that.